# Data has both text and number, I need to move to another sheet from master but only the numbers show up...I need both

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I've used this formula

```
=query('Form Responses'!1:136,"Select * Where E='name'")
```

but all I get is the numerical value entered in a cell. If someone enters both a number and text the cell is blank. In the example below Pitt entered 7 VAC however the cell is blank. It has data in the master. Is there a way to pull ALL of the information in a cell even if it is a combination?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.